# How can I make units in my board game equal in stats yet unique?

Tags: 2d

I am making a board game, but can't figure out how to make the units overall equal in their stats, with each one being individual?

Comment: "Overall equal in their stats"? Do you have a couple of examples?

Comment: In case the OP is still interested in this question: This question might get better answers if you add more information about your game mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about game balancing? It's tricky. It takes finesse and lots of tweaking.

Besides play testing, calculating specific scenarios and common sense, there is not a lot you can really do.

One thing you can do is make some assumptions about the 'value' or 'weight' of each different stat so that you can abstract them and then they can be compared directly. Then you can allocate X number of abstract points to each unit and adjust the stats until its allocation is used up.

For instance, for the sake of a simple example say each unit has movement speed and armor rating. Speed is worth 1pt, armor is worth 2 and each unit can have 10 points. One unit could have a speed of 2 and armor of 4 while another could have an armor of 1 and a speed of 8.

Setup a spreadsheet with calculated fields to help out.

After play testing, when you find the balance is not right, tweak the weighting or the stats themselves. You will probably need to do a LOT of iterations, tweaking and testing... Have fun :)